# how do setting websocket proxy and cors in nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, server, cors

I already set proxy in nginx and set up a web socket server in tomcat

if, I makes a request with http://MY_URL/api/ws/data, the port should change from 80 to 8060
also, those finally must be https

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (I`m using default.conf)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

location /api/ {
  proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

location /api/ws/data/ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8060;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
```

when, i makes request in local server

**Failed to load http://MY_URL/api/ws/data/info?t=1525237291534: Redirect from 'http://MY_URL/api/ws/data/info?t=1525237291534' to 'https://MY_URL/api/ws/data/info?t=1525237291534' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.**

how do setting websocket proxy and cors in nginx?

++++

after this chrome execute with --disable-web-security command,

**Bad Request**

**This combination of host and port requires TLS.**

what is mean it? and how do solve this problem?

Comment: P.S. It already set ssl redirection in aws cloud front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the CORS issue, try using *more_set_headers* instead of *add_header*:

```
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers:DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
```

The *more_set_headers* directive is part of the [HttpHeadersMore](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module which is included in the [nginx-extras flavor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553937/what-is-the-difference-between-the-core-full-extras-and-light-packages-for-ngi#556382) of nginx, you can install it on ubuntu 16 by doing:

> sudo apt-get install nginx-extras

Comment: "etc?". can you inculde this better?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but "etc" stands for "et cetera" which means "and so on" and was being used to depict that you can keep adding headers beyond those exemplified; removed for clarity.

Comment: Hahaha sorry i was really tired. I meant can you include all the complete headers and where they go inside the `server` config. It's fine, i figured it out by creating a new `api` domain for my websocket connection and using the traditional headers

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a separate domain for your websocket API. Is this ideal? No, but it will save you hours of searching stackoverflow for shorter solutions.

This is my second go-around of trying to find a better way and ultimately adding a new domain (or subdomain) with CORS is much easier and totally works.

```
server {
    server_name  socketapi.ddns.net;


    location / {

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

        #Enables socket connectiosn over https, will forward to the http version
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3050; #could be localhost if Echo and NginX are on the same box
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
     client_max_body_size 20M; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/socketapi.ddns.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/socketapi.ddns.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```